# HTML nav menu/form list that redirects on button click

Tags: html, nav

Here is what I'm trying to do, and I feel as though maybe I'm overthinking it. I can easily make a dropdown nav list, but what I need is to combine two different dropdown lists to give a user options, then when they click the button it will send them to a page that corresponds with their choices.

> For example, dropdown list one: What type of advice do you need?
>   -Career
>   -Relationships
>   -Health
>   
>   droplist two: What layout do you want?
>   -Quick and Dirty
>   -Standard
>   -In-depth

Then I just need to program in the link to every combination of these pages. How do program in the correct redirects depending on the selections?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a pair of drop-down menus like this:

```
<form method="post"> 
  <p>What type of advice do you need?
  <br><select id="s1">
      <option>Career</option>
      <option>Relationships</option>
      <option>Health</option>
  </select>

  <p>What layout do you want?
  <br><select id="s2">
        <option>Quick and Dirty</option>
        <option>Standard</option>
        <option>In-depth</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" onclick="send(this.form)" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

The button at the end of the form, when clicked calls a function that will redirect to the page you want comparing the items selected in each menu. The function should receive a reference to the form (passed in `this.form`), get the selected indexes and text (or values, if you use them in each `option`) and test them in a condicional branch:

```
function send(form) {
    var s1 = document.getElementById("s1");
    var s2 = document.getElementById("s2");

    var choice1 = s1.options[s1.selectedIndex].text;      
    var choice2 = s2.options[s2.selectedIndex].text; 

    if (choice1 == "Career" && choice2 == "Quick and Dirty") {
        location.href = "http://quickdirtycareers.com";
    } else if (choice1 == "Career" && choice2 == "Standard") { 
        location.href = "http://standardcareers.com";
    } else {
        location.href = "http://careers.stackoverflow.com";
    }
}
```

Here's a Fiddle with a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/TNZ9A/

(There are many other ways to do it, adding CSS, dynamic selection, focus, etc. It's easier to add these enhancements using JQuery.)